# There are $n$ points in the plane, not all collinear. Prove that there exists a line passing through exactly $2$ points.

Tags: geometry

I try the method of induction on it, but I fail at the last step.
I assume that the statement is true for all planes with less than n points.
Then if I add one more point to the plane so that it is not collinear to the line with exaclty two points on it, the statement is true for the plane with n points.
However, if the new point is added on the line with exactly two points, how can we make sure that there is still a line passing through exactly two points?

Comment: Previous related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772820/prove-sylvester-gallai-theorem-using-combinatorics and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754430/sylvester-gallai-problem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608906/proof-of-sylvester-gallai-theorem-using-induction and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531070/examples-of-famous-problems-resolved-easily/532096#532096 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259939/are-there-finitely-many-points-in-mathbb-r2-that-satisfy-this-condition/3260247#3260247 and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Sylvester-Gallai Theorem. You can find many proofs on the internet, including in the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem

See the following notes for a nice and slick proof: [http://web.stanford.edu/~yuvalwig/math/teaching/WhatsThePoint.pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eyuvalwig/math/teaching/WhatsThePoint.pdf)

Comment: In Kelly's proof, what does ordinary of a line mean?

Comment: The terminology is "ordinary line" (rather than "ordinary of a line"). This is defined at the beginning of the article; it's a line that goes through just two points in the collection.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now, the proof is so clever.